# Check if file exists using bash inside Java program?

Tags: linux, bash, java

So I am witting a java program for interacting with filesystem. 
Java program itself cannot run as super user. I created a special user for this program and gave it some special privileges to run some commands without password (via visudo file).

So I I'd like to check if a file exist. I used:
`if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory())` but the problem is this fails if I am checking if files exist that is read/write protected or if it belongs to another user.
That is why I need to use bash. for example, when I am retrieving information about file I use the following:
`String[] command = new String[] { "sudo", "stat", filepath, "-c", "%F@@%s@@%U@@%G@@%X@@%Y@@%Z" };`
`process = runtime.exec(command);` and then just parse the output.

For example moving a file I use this:

```
String[] command = new String[] {
            "sudo",
            "-u",
            user,
            "mv",
            source,
            target
};
```

So now I am looking for a way to get simple true/false response when checking if file exist.

I think I could use `find` command or something similar?

Comment: `man test`, look for `-f`

Comment: I am using test, but the problem is with java... when I contruct the command I get soemthing like this: 
`String[] command = new String[] {"test", "-f", path, "&&", "echo", "true"};`
then the error is that && is unrecognized character

Comment: Why do you need an `echo` afterwards? Use the return code directly. 0 if it exists, 1 otherwise

Comment: I totally forgot about that. Yes it works great! Should I answer my own question with the answer? Or will you and then I mark it as resolved? 

Also another quick question. My program should let users download files from the machine where program is running. I'll use mv to move files to /tmp folder to which my java program has access (it cannot access user files directly as a regular user)

Comment: I'm not confident enough in Java to write an answer, so feel free to do it yourself. Also, I don't see the question.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my issue by using the following command:
`String[] command = new String[] { "sudo", "-u", user, "test", "-f", path };`

Where user is user who I am running command as. And path is the path-to-file we are testing.

I then read the execute and read command's output in the code below. 
I hope it helps someone someday...

```
process = runtime.exec(command);

            errbr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
            while ((messageLine = errbr.readLine()) != null) {
                message += messageLine + ";";
            }

            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            while ((messageLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                message += messageLine;
            }
```